# I have a question about how the function works

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

While solving the algorithm, there is a part that I do not understand about how the function works.

```
function letterCombinations(digits) {
    var map = ['0', '1', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqrs', 'tuv', 'wxyz'];
    var res = [];
    var prefix = [];

    if (digits.length) {
        traverse(0);
    }
    return res;

    function traverse(idx) {
        if (idx === digits.length) {
            return res.push(prefix.join(''));
        }

        var str = map[digits[idx] - '0'];

        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            prefix.push(str[i]);
            traverse(idx + 1);
            prefix.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

When the conditional statement inside the traverse function is encountered

```
 if (idx === digits.length) {
        return res.push(prefix.join(''));
    }
```

Why is the pop method executed without exiting the function?

```
prefix.pop()
```

Comment: prefix acts as a kind of book-keeping, push recurse pop, this is done inside a loop, no need to return untill the loop is over

Comment: insert a `debugger;` keyword before `prefix.pop()` and step though in the devtool, you'll understand the process very intuitively.

Answer (score 1):

You wording is kinda ambiguous, but I think get what you're really asking.

The `prefix.pop()` is a line inside `traverse()` function, and the `traverse()` *recursively* calls itself.

Take for example `letterCombinations('23')` where corresponding `str` would be `2: 'abc', 3: 'def'`. The process can be visualized as following pseudo code:

```
traverse(0)
  i=0, push('a') // prefix=['a']

  traverse(1)
    loop when i=0:
      push('d')       // prefix=['a', 'd']
      traverse(2)     // since `2==digits.length`, it's a short-circuit return
                      // no `pop()` called inside `traverse(2)`
      pop_1() -> 'd'  // prefix=['a']
    
    loop when i=1:
      push('e')       // prefix=['a', 'e']
      traverse(2)     // short-circuit return
      pop_1() -> 'e'  // prefix=['a']

    loop when i=3:
      ...
    
  pop_0()
```

You get confused because you're fixing your eye on the `prefix.pop()` line of code in `traverse(0)`, marked as `pop_0()` in the pseudo code. But you forget to trace the recursion.

Use your imagination and step into `traverse(1)`, you'll find another `prefix.pop()` call there, marked as `pop_1()`.

So to answer your question:

> Why is the pop method executed without exiting the function?

You're right about the fact that, we haven't exit `traverse(0)` yet, but the pop method is actually called inside `traverse(1)`. Out there, we've exit `traverse(2)` because of the short-circuit return.

Answer (score 0):

The `.pop()` method has nothing to do with the function it's being called in. That method is part of the array object, [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

The `return` statement actually exists the function. So if you want when `.pop()` is called, the function to be exited write:

```
return prefix.pop();
```

Or if you want the current iteration of the loop finished, you can call [continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)